# Webpack 2 duplicating modules across bundles?

Tags: webpack-2

I'm new to Webpack 2.  When my bundles are created, some modules are duplicated across bundles.  Here's my webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    node: {
      fs: "empty"
    },
    context: __dirname,
    entry: {
        "vendor": "./src/vendor-bundle-config.ts",
        "app" : "./src/app/app.module"
    },  
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: './'
    }   
}
```

and my vendor-bundle-config:

```
// Angular
import '@angular/platform-browser';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/common';
import '@angular/http';
import '@angular/router';

// RxJS
import 'rxjs';
```

No matter what I do, rxjs (and maybe other modules, I haven't checked further) is duplicated across both bundles.  The odd thing is that I'm testing this all out with a very basic Angular project - it has the AppComponent and that's it.  The only place rxjs is referenced currently is in `package.json` and `vendor-bundle-config`

I've tried configuring the CommonsChunkPlugin but it didn't seem to do anything.  I'm not sure if that's something that I should look into further.

EDIT: Here's the config for the CommonsChunkPlugin as best I can recall it:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: "commons",
  filename: "commons.js",
})
```

This is from the webpack documentation example.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Show the `CommonsChunkPlugin` configuration.

Comment: I no longer have the CommonsChunkPlugin config, but I updated the post above with what I recall it being - based off of the webpack documentation example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin's `name` option is the chunk's name you want to separate from entries.So,change it to `vendor`. See the [code splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-libraries) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  I was missing the minChunks option in my CommonsChunkPlugin configuration.  It needs to look like this to work:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: "commons",
  filename: "commons.js",
  minChunks: 2     <-- this is what I was missing
})
```